# Compiling and Running a netbeans GUI Application in Unix commandline

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, command-line, gui-builder

I need to make a GUI Application for my class , so I want to make sure I can transfer a netbeans project using the GUI Builder (I know how to make it without it, but that's more time consuming and I think it would look neater without me guessing coordinates etc. and I was use to the netbeans GUI builder) from netbeans onto unix and compile it.  So here's what I did I made a new JFrame form (using netbeans GUI Builder) called StartFrame.java and another called MenuFrame.java.  (keep in mind that it ran with no errors in netbeans) StartFrame creates a new instance of MenuFrame and opens it on it's first run.  So I transferred all of it onto the unix system.  So at first I tried compiling it, but of course it got errors, saying that org.jdesktop... isn't found.
Okay so I've already searched stackoverflow and the web for this.  So I ended up getting the swing-layout-1.0.4.jar from the libraries in netbeans. 
I'm kind of new at compiling from command line, but I put them all in the same folder, and while I was in that directory.
I did

```
javac StartFrame.java -cp swing-layout-1.0.4.jar
```

and I got the error that NoClassDefFoundException: MenuFrame even though it is in the same folder.  So then I tried

```
javac StartFrame.java MenuFrame.java -cp swing-layout-1.0.4.jar
```

and it compiled fine with no errors.  So then It created 6 files StartFrame.class StartFrame$1.class StartFrame$2.class StartFrame$3.class StartFrame$4.class MenuFrame.class
I tried running it with

```
java -cp swing-layout-1.0.4.jar StartFrame
```

and it had a NoClassDefFoundException: StartFrame.  I searched the web for fixes for this and stack overflow and found similar (not exact though) problems like this, but none of those fixed it.

Comment: is there a package statement in StartFrame.java and/or MenuFrame.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `dist/README.TXT` will tell you how to proceed. Type `ant -p` at the command line to see that available commands: `ant run` is usually good.

Addendum:

> The machine doesn't have ant installed

That would be unusual, so you should certainly verify it. You may need to add the current directory to the path, e.g.

```
java -cp .:swing-layout-1.0.4.jar StartFrame
```

Comment: It only gives you instructions for running the already,netbeans built jar though, It doesn't say how to actually compile it correctly in unix, and run it without an executable.

Comment: That's where the `ant -p` comes in. Of course, the destination host must have a JDK to compile your code and a JRE to run it. I move NetBeans projects among disparate platforms routinely.

Comment: Is there any way to use java/javac to do it? the machine doesn't have ant installed and it belongs to the school.

Comment: oh wow thanks a lot, adding the current directory to the path worked.  I didn't think you would need to do that since for javac it wasn't necessary.  Now it runs fine.